# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'am working on a JSP site with a servlet and a Tomcatserver.
At the moment I can't figure out the problem for this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder
```

I already googled for this problem and tried every possibility.

The jdome2 is included

[image]

and there is also no fault about the SAXBuild function in the code

[image]

Here is the stacktrace I get when I run the project

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path                  [/Quiz] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException:      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at de.fhwgt.quiz.loader.FilesystemLoader.getCatalogs(FilesystemLoader.java:114)
at de.fhwgt.quiz.application.Quiz.getCatalogList(Quiz.java:274)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:194)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I aleady tried to use jdom1.x.x instead of jdom2 but it didn't work

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: It is not sufficient that the JDOM library is present in the IDE, but it must also be present in the webserver. How and what do you deploy to your webserver?

Comment: Check the jar is present in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simply move this `jdom` jar to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`.

I am assuming that you are not using build tool like `maven` or `gradle`.

Comment: Thanks. Stephan already told me that in a comment above. But that was the solution. Thanks again.